# Perl multidimensional array access

Tags: arrays, perl

Lets say the multidimensional array is like this,

```
$myarray = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

Trying to access it in three ways,

```
print $myarray->[1][1] #prints 5
print $myarray->[1]->[1] #also prints 5
print $myarray[1][1] #prints nothing
```

I can't figure the difference between the first and the second type of access. Specifically, second one is more explicit but still first one works. That compels me to think third better work as well (which I know won't because `myarray` is actually a reference and not an array).

Comment: Which one first, second or third?

Comment: For the third, try `print $$myarray[1][1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three points

1. `$myarray` is holding an array reference, not an array.
2. `$myarray` and `@myarray` are different variables
3. Perl doesn't really do multidimensional arrays

All references are held in scalars, so all references are held in variables that start with `$`.

The `[ ... ]` creates an anonymous array reference so `[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` is creating an anonymous array reference containing 3 anonymous array references each containing 3 scalars.

This means that the assignment to `$myarray` is assigning the outer anonymous array reference to it.

In order two access what a reference is pointing two you need to dereference it. You can do that by placing the symbol for the type of what the reference points to in front of the reference like `@$myarray`. So `$$myarray[0]` is the first element of the anonymous array held in the reference `$myarray` or you can use the indirect syntax `$myarray->[0]`.

In your example `$myarray->[0]` holds the array reference `[1,2,3]` So this can be dereferenced in the same way giving `$myarray->[0]->[0]` This says dereference `$myarray` and give me the first element, which is an array reference, then dereference that and give me the first element of that.

This gives your second example.

Perl allows you to drop the `->` between `]` and `[` as well as `}` and `{` for anonymous hashes, as syntactic sugar. This gives `$myarray->[0][0]` which is your first example.

Your third example is looking for the first element of `@myarray` which is a different variable than `$myarray`. if you had put `use strict` at the top of your script Perl would have caught this error for you.

It is a good idea to put

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

As the first two lines of any Perl script or module as they will trap a multitude of bad and potentially fatal errors in your Program. If you are debugging a program then adding `use diagnostics` under `use strict` gives more verbose messages.

Comment: Minor note: while `@$myarray` is how you dereference it as an array, to dereference and access one element would be `$$myarray[0]`, which is then equivalent to the arrow notation. The same way that you use `@array` and `$array[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

The first and second examples are functionally equivalent. One is just syntactic sugar for the other.

The third is semantically different. Whereas it is acceptable to omit `->` operators between indices, it is not acceptable to do so between identifiers or subroutine calls and indices if the variable (or subroutine) contains (or returns) a reference, because Perl will treat those as non-references in that case.

There is no situation where `$array->[1][2]` could mean anything aside from `$array->[1]->[2]`, but if it were permissible to omit the arrow between the identifier and the first index, it would be ambiguous as to whether the structure being indexed into looked like `[1,...]` or `(1,...)`, which are different things.

Comment: Note that `$array->[1]->[2]` is the same as `@{ @{ $myarray }[0] }[0]`

Answer (score 2):

`$myarray->[1]` means "look up index 1 in an array using the array reference stored in `$myarray`".

`$myarray[1]` means "look up index 1 in the array `@myarray`".

The two variables `$myarray` and `@myarray` have no connection at all.